# How to show/hide a layout when gridView item is selected/unselected in Android using Custom BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, baseadapter

this is my Adapter class

```
  public class GridViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


private List<ProductParameterBO> availList;


private LayoutInflater inflater;

Context context;

public GridViewCustomAdapter(Context ctx,List<ProductParameterBO> list){
    this.context = ctx;
    this.availList = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return availList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return availList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    ProductParameterBO c = availList.get(position);
   // long id = c.getTimeId();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position,View convertView,final ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
  final TeeTimeHolder holder;
    if (row == null){
        inflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_row,parent,false);
        holder = new TeeTimeHolder();
        holder.myImage =(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
        holder.imageflip =(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.img_flp);
        holder.name =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView47);
        holder.edit =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView49);
        holder.rl =(RelativeLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.grid_img_ovrly);
      //  holder.row =(RelativeLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder =(TeeTimeHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    holder.name.setText(availList.get(position).getParameterName());
    holder.myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.toi);
    holder.rl.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    return row;
}




static class TeeTimeHolder {
    ImageView myImage,imageflip;

    TextView name,edit;

    RelativeLayout rl;
 }
}
```

i just want to show Relativelayout r1 when row is selected and when i select the next row ,previous row must hide Relativelayout r1 layout and show on row which is selected.. Now in my case when i select the next row ,then its not hiding from previous row ..layout still showing on all row which i select.

Please help me to sort out this problem..any help would be appreciated in advanced..

Comment: hi everyOne plsss help me to sort out this problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
 int priviousPosition=0;
    ArrayList<View> viewList= new ArrayList<View>();
    holder.rl.setTag(position);
    viewList.add(holder.rl);
    row.findViewById(R.id.grid_img_ovrly).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v1) { 

    View v=viewList.get(priviousPosition);
    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    int postition=(Integer) v1.getTag();
    priviousPosition=postition;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    });
```